# How to create an ssh tunnel every time rails loads in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, splunk

What's the convention for where to place a line of bash code that needs to get executed every time i start up rails locally? I'm creating a tunnel (`ssh -gL8089:splunk-server:8089 myserver`) so that I can extract splunk results locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can drop your code

```
 system("ssh ...")
```

into environments/environment_name.rb if you need it only for a particular environment.  If you just always need it I'd throw it into environments.rb or boot.rb

Comment: I tried that -- now, every time I run rails -s, it creates the tunnel in the same terminal window, and so rails doesn't actually load (localhost:3000 is unreachable)

Comment: do you know if there is any way to have this command run in the background (& doesn't work) or in another terminal?

Comment: ahh yes, you could run it in a new thread, like Thread.new { system("ssh ...") }, or you could use IO.popen and friends, I suppose...I *think* the child process will die when the server exits, so it might work.